# Exporting multiple maps on rendercomplete in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, export, pdf, rendering

I have this project where I have 4 different maps next to each other. These maps have different layers on top of them so they can be compared. Now I want the user to be able to export those 4 maps to a pdf file. I found some documentation on how to export a map to pdf: [Documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html).

I edited this down to make it compatible in my react project. At this point I am able to export one map. But not all 4 maps in one pdf file. This is because a map can only be added to a pdf once the map is rendered. But I can only check the "rendercomplete" on one map at a time. Is there a way to check if all maps in a Array are rendered and then execute the code to export to a pdf? In my example i have the `this.Maps[0]` just checking the first map in the Array. I need to check all maps in that Array and when they are all rendered the code needs to be executed.

```
  exportMap() {
    this.Maps[0].getMap().once("rendercomplete", () => {
      var pdf = new jsPDF("landscape", undefined, "a4");
      var viewResolution = this.Maps[0].getMap().getView().getResolution();
      var mapCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var size = this.Maps[0].getMap().getSize();
      mapCanvas.width = size[0];
      mapCanvas.height = size[1];
      var mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext("2d");

      this.Maps[0]
        .getMap()
        .getViewport()
        .querySelectorAll(".ol-layer canvas")
        .forEach((canvas) => {
          if (canvas !== undefined) {
            if (canvas.width > 0) {
              console.log(canvas);
              var opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
              mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === "" ? 1 : Number(opacity);
              var transform = canvas.style.transform;
              // Get the transform parameters from the style's transform matrix
              var matrix = transform
                .match(/^matrix\(([^]*)\)$/)[1]
                .split(",")
                .map(Number);
              // Apply the transform to the export map context
              CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
                mapContext,
                matrix
              );
              mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
            }
          }
        });
      pdf.addImage(mapCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), "JPEG", 0, 0, 297, 210);
      // Reset original map size
      this.Maps[0].getMap().setSize(size);
      this.Maps[0].getMap().getView().setResolution(viewResolution);
      document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
      pdf.save("map.pdf");
    });
    this.Maps[0].getMap().renderSync();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to render all four maps (which could complete in any order) and store the data urls until you have all of them, then you can create the pdf

```
  exportMaps() {
    const jpegs = new Array(4);
    let jpegCount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      this.Maps[i].getMap().once("rendercomplete", () => {
 
      ...

        jpegs[i] = mapCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        jpegCount++;
        // Reset original map size
        this.Maps[i].getMap().setSize(size);
        this.Maps[i].getMap().getView().setResolution(viewResolution);

        if (jpegCount == 4) {
          document.body.style.cursor = "auto";

          // add all jpegs to the pdf and save it

        }

      });
      this.Maps[i].getMap().renderSync();
    }
  }
```